# Estimating t-statistics from Johannsen cointegration method in ca.jo in R

Tags: r

I'm working my way through the vignette workded example in the “vars” library in R.  I’m understand most of the example in the vignette expect Table 5 of the vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf)

Running the following code, I see where the cointegrating vector and loadings point estimates are derived, but I do not understand where the t-statistics have been derived.

I ran this code:

`library("vars")
data("Canada")
Canada <- Canada[, c("prod", "e", "U", "rw")]
vecm <- ca.jo(Canada[, c("rw", "prod", "e", "U")], type = "trace", ecdet = "trend", K = 3, spec = "transitory")
vecm.r1 <- cajorls(vecm, r = 1)`

And got these eigenvectors and weightings,

```
    Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

               rw.l1     prod.l1       e.l1       U.l1   trend.l1
rw.l1     1.00000000   1.0000000  1.0000000   1.000000  1.0000000
prod.l1   0.54487553  -3.0021508  0.7153696  -7.173608  0.4087221
e.l1     -0.01299605  -3.8867890 -2.0625220 -30.429074 -3.3884676
U.l1      1.72657188 -10.2183404 -5.3124427 -49.077209 -5.1326687
trend.l1 -0.70918872   0.6913363 -0.3643533  11.424630  0.1157125

Weights W:
(This is the loading matrix)

              rw.l1      prod.l1        e.l1          U.l1      trend.l1
rw.d   -0.084814510  0.048563997 -0.02368720 -0.0016583069  5.722004e-12
prod.d -0.011994081  0.009204887 -0.09921487  0.0020567547 -7.478364e-12
e.d    -0.015606039 -0.038019447 -0.01140202 -0.0005559337 -1.229460e-11
U.d    -0.008659911  0.020499657  0.02896325  0.0009140795  1.103862e-11
```

Which give me the correct alpha and beta values in Table 5.

But I have no idea where the t-statistics in table 5 have been derived in the code.  Can anybody out there point me in the right direction please?

Regards,

James

Answer (score 4):

My biggest gripe with `urca`: it does not calculate t-statistics for the beta vectors. It looks like the author maybe at some point wanted to include the feature (hence table 5 in the vignette you cite above) but did not get around to actually doing it.

The good news: **For the case of one cointegrating vector (r=1), there is sample code available to get the standard errors**. See this [discussion thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-retrieve-standard-errors-of-cointegrating-vector-from-vars-urca-td4655136.html)

## Standard Errors for the Long-Run Cointegrating Relationship with urca when there is a single cointegrating vector

Continuing from your example above, the code given by the nabble thread discussed above is:

```
 alpha <- coef(vecm.r1$rlm)[1, ]  # the coefficients on ecm1
 beta <- vecm.r1$beta  # the point estimates of beta

 resids <- resid(vecm.r1$rlm) 
 N <- nrow(resids) 
 sigma <- crossprod(resids) / N 

 ## t-stats for beta 
 beta.se <- sqrt(diag(kronecker(solve(crossprod(vecm@RK[, -1])), 
                                solve(t(alpha) %*% solve(sigma) %*% alpha)))) 
 beta.t <- c(NA, beta[-1] / beta.se) 
 names(beta.t) <- rownames(vecm.r1$beta) 
 beta.t
```

This reproduces exactly the standard errors given by the vignette.

## Compare with Gretl

If we run the same model with gretl, we get exactly identical point estimates for beta but the standard errors roughly agree:

[image: Gretl Standard Errors for Cointegrating Vector]

## Bonus: Create LaTeX table of the cointegrating vector with standard errors using urca and texreg

You need to write a slightly clumsy "extract" function to assemble the standard errors and point estimates together into the form that `texreg` likes:

```
 extract.cajo_beta <- function(cajo, orls) {
   alpha <- coef(orls$rlm)[1, ];
   resids <- resid(orls$rlm);
   N <- nrow(resids);
   sigma <- crossprod(resids) / N;

   # get standard errors and p-values
   beta <- orls$beta
   beta.se <- sqrt(diag(kronecker(solve(crossprod(cajo@RK[, -1])), 
                                  solve(t(alpha) %*% solve(sigma) %*% alpha))));
   beta.se2 <- c(NA, beta.se);
   beta.t <- c(NA, beta[-1] / beta.se);
   beta.pval <- dt(beta.t, df= orls$rlm$df.residual)

   tr <- createTexreg(coef.names = as.character(rownames(beta)), coef = as.numeric(beta), se = beta.se2, 
         pvalues = beta.pval,
         # remove this goodness of fit measure afterwards from the table
         gof.names = c('Dummy'), gof = c(1), gof.decimal = c(FALSE)
   );
   return(tr);
 }
```

Then run:

```
 > screenreg(extract.cajo_beta(vecm, vecm.r1))

 =================
           Model 1
 -----------------
 rw.l1      1.00  

 prod.l1    0.54  
           (0.61) 
 e.l1      -0.01  
           (0.68) 
 U.l1       1.73  
           (1.45) 
 trend.l1  -0.71 *
           (0.28) 
 -----------------
 Dummy      1     
 =================
 *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

Comment: When you convert Gretl's printout from standard errors to t-ratios the results are all within about ten percent of the other code you quote. I suppose that's what you mean when you say they agree only "roughly". I don't know right now how exactly gretl calculates the standard errors, but for a sample size of T=81 I'd say that already using a different estimate for the error variance can easily explain that difference. (In the code you cite N is used in the denominator, which is certainly OK but not the only option.)

Comment: @SvenS. fair enough - the standard errors are close, so changed the wording of the answer :)

Comment: @user3096626 Thx for the code. In your code, you give how to calculate p value for beta taking into account `df= orls$rlm$df.residual` degree of freedom for beta. What is degree of freedom for alpha? How can we calculate degree of freedom for alpha? How can we calculate p value for alpha? It would also be best if you include gretl code to which you gave print-screen. Many thanks.